# Painting several layers at once

Tags: layers

I'm using Blender and UE4, and I've got a problem:
For most materials I use several textures (Color, Roughness, Metalic, etc.) I recently discovered painting with Blender and I love it, but I would like to know how can I paint several layers at once. For example, I might have a mesh with a Color and a Roughness layer, and when I add rust to it, I want the Roughness layer to also be affected.  Any ideas?